# How to set up a tcp server on a personal computer

Tags: python-3.x, tcp

I'm not that experienced with networking - hence why I'm asking this question - so please have patience with my inexperience.

What I want to do is set up a server on my computer that my friend's computer could connect to through the internet and we could play a game (very surprising indeed). A vague idea that I had was I could run a VM to handle it. My questions are:

1. Is there a way I could establish a connection between our computers without having to pay for a separate server?
2. Is there a Python 3 library that's good for beginners (in networking - not Python) that can do this task?

Note 1: It is a turn based game so the processing does not have to be really fast.

Note 2: I have a basic understanding of sockets, servers, etc, I'm just not familiar enough with them to find what I'm looking for elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with netcat? What do you mean by "(in networking - not Python)". The reason I ask if your familiar with netcat is because if you are sockets should not be too hard to program (I say that respectfully they can be weird at first glance). Your most likely going to have to open a port on your router to do this. Depending in the game will be the complexity of programming this. But basically this is what you want right.

TCP Server (Listening) (Your Friends House)

TCP Client (You)

TCL Client -> TCP Server

If your gonna be using a windows gui just use VNC Viewer: https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/ or TeamViewer: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/ or enable RDP.

Comment: By  "(in networking - not Python)," I mean users who are beginners in networking, not new Python developers. Do you know of a Linux equivalent to VNC Viewer?

Comment: Nice linux is 10/10 you can use VNC in linux I'm assuming your using ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04 there is one tutorial however you can find many tutorials on how to install VNC in ubuntu or debain. Hope this helps!